# How to get Current Location through GPS in Android

Tags: android

I am developing application based on google maps in that current location of user has to display in map. i have google it and find solution but when i run the code it doesnt shows the current location instead it showing google map alone. My code is below

```
 public class GPSLocation extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private GPSLocationListener locationListener;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   // mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    // enable Street view by default
   // mapView.setStreetView(true);

    // enable to show Satellite view
    // mapView.setSatellite(true);

    // enable to show Traffic on map
    // mapView.setTraffic(true);

  //  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

  //  mapController = mapView.getController();
   // mapController.setZoom(16);




    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);


}
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
    public GPSLocationListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("onLocationChanged");
          GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                  (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                  (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));


      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
          "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
          " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mapController.animateTo(point);
      mapController.setZoom(16);
      mapView.invalidate();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("OnLocationChanged value is null");
    }
  }



@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}





}
```

I dont know where i have done mistake.Its not even entering into GPSLocationListener class. please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks I got so much help from your code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is your gps active. Change min distance and min time. For example:

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10,30,locationListener);
```

Comment: I have tried but again it showing only map not the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a device or emulator? Because on the emulator you have to manually input coordinates.

Also, make sure one of the follwing is in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: i am checking in emulator only.if i given coordinates it has to run the code in GPSLocationListener but its not even entering into that class then how its possible? yes i have given permission in manifest file

Comment: In eclipse click 'window' in the top toolbar then 'show view' and look for 'Emulator Control' if its not in that list click 'other' and select it from there. Then, in the view that appears scroll to the bottom where it says 'Location Controls' and change the coordinates in there then press 'send'.

Comment: I have change the coordinates in emulator control lang as 9 58' and long as 78 10' as current location but it again showing map only not the particular location. and its not entering into GPSLocationListener class..

Comment: @deepa try to check in device.. sometime on emulator GPS wont run.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line of code also. It worked for me.

```
LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORk_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

If it still doesn't work can you please give the Log Details?

Answer (score 0):

Recent Google Maps V2 lets you implement **OnMyLocationChangeListener**, so you don't need to implement (and set) a custom LocationSource.